# PDO inner join?

Tags: sql, database, pdo

I have 2 tables. I am running a query on one table, but I need that query to ONLY include 'active' results listed in table 1.

```
//-- Get a list of all expired docs in all categories except archive
    $q2 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(rmid) FROM rmDocs WHERE cat!=:cat and expDate!=:blankExpDate and expDate < (NOW() + INTERVAL $rmDocExpireCheck DAY)");
    $q2->execute(array(':blankExpDate'=>"0000-00-00", ':cat'=>"arc"));
    $numExpired = $q2->fetchColumn();
```

The other table is rawProducts. The query above needs to include `SELECT id FROM rawProducts WHERE active=1`

Should that be an inner join?

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work...

```
//-- Get a list of all expired docs in all categories except archive
    $q2 = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(rmDocs.rmid) FROM rmDocs INNER JOIN rawProducts ON rmDocs.rmid = rawProducts.id WHERE rawProducts.active=:active AND cat!=:cat and expDate!=:blankExpDate and expDate < (NOW() + INTERVAL $rmDocExpireCheck DAY)");
    $q2->execute(array(':blankExpDate'=>"0000-00-00", ':cat'=>"arc", ':active'=>1));
    $numExpired = $q2->fetchColumn();
```